# Parametric stabilizer circuit optimization for reducing ripple

Tags: voltage-regulator, analog, power-electronics, pre-regulator

We have a TV mainboard that will be used in cars. The input voltage will have lots of noise and not be regulated well. So we want to use a parametric stabilizer at the 12V input. Acumulator voltage may vary between 11V to 15.5V, we determined that we can accept input voltage levels between 11 V to 13.8 V and required current is 450 to 500 mA. Our stabilizer circuit do start to regulate input voltage when it exceeds 13.4V but with big ripples.

This is our standard Panel switch circuit in the red line and Parametric stabilizer which I added in green line:

[image: PS]

The circuit in the red line is fixed standart power shutdown circuit of us and I can not make any changes on that. So I added the parametric stabilizer circuit in green line. The problem with this stabilizer is that it manages to trigger when the threshold is exceeded but it has enormous ripples:

[image: waveform]

*Here the yellow line is output and purple line is voltage reference's output (pin 2).*

The limitation is I can not use a DC-DC or LDO chip for this design (because they are expensive, this project is going for Mass production) and I have to implement this stabilizer with only components we have in our stock. So if you suggest any modification on this circuit or if you could suggest any circuit  for inside of the green line here it would be very nice. At this point I have to warn you that we do not use opamps! This circuit can be formed by only transistors, references etc. simple components.

What I have tried so far:

I tried a shunt 1 nF capacitor with R537: it did not do much, just made so little.

I took out input capacitor C1029: it made it worse.

I put 22 uF large output capacitor at output: did not make a difference.

I tried 1k-1pF RC compensation between cathode and reference: not much difference.

Comment: The bounty has been judged, but does some of the suggestions work in practice, too? We're curious, let us know!

Comment: @user287001 your suggestion made ripple decrease down to 300 mV but it was not acceptable for us. So I removed the fixed circuit in the red line and cancelled the stabilizer. Now I just use 100% Duty cycle DC-DC with a little cost-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: You have not at all an input capacitor. One should exist between the DC input and the ground. Its function would be to short incoming DC supply noise and to tame the inductance of DC input wires.

C1209 makes your mosfet very slow. You should rather to prevent random on-off state glitches by preventing T1002 to get any spikes to its base. Start by moving the lower wire of C1029 to GND.

C1030 should exist, at least several uFs is needed. This is the brute force way to prevent those voltage jumps that are caused by current changes so fast that the regulator can't handle them due its limited speed.

**The 10 kHz oscillation:** The frequency is quite the same where the gain of AP432 has dropped at least 6 dB and its phase lag respectively is easily 45 degrees. Combined with the seriously slow-motion fet and the saturated  (=very slow) T1002B you probably have enough building blocks for a good multivibrator.

Reduce the open loop gain. If by any means possible, insert a 1 kOhm resistor to the emitter of T1002B. If impossible, then try to create a dominant compensation pole by inserting a capacitor between the C and B of T1002B. several hundred pFs, probably several nFs is needed. This forces to have a big output capacitor. Check by oscilloscope that maximum output current off-step does not cause too high voltage peak when the DC input is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The "trigger" behavior needs to be removed, and a smooth behavior implemented.
The fast bandwidth of the AP432SRG-7 caused oscillation. And the high loop gain
1) the Pch FET
2) the NPN with its grounded emitter
3) the AP432 with 10,000Hz bandwidth
means this loop will skeg/flip from one state to another.

Try a HUGE cap on base of NPN, to ensure the oscillation will slow down.

Then implement a VERY LOW GAIN error amplifier, such as PNP, base tied to top of ShuntReg, with 100Kohm from Emitter to Vout, and collector tied to base of NPN. You need VERY LOW gain in the error amplifier, because of the high gain in PChan and in the NPN.

Answer (score 1):

The AP432 shunt regulator has an Ron of 0.2 ohms.
The input resistor is 9.1KOhms||40Kohms ~ 8Kohms, thus the GAIN is 8,000 / 0.2 = 40,000X or 92dB. This "regulator loop" has way too much gain.

Replace the AP432 with an NPN, 9.1KOhm in the emitter, collector tied to junction of 40K and 9.1KOhm. For moderate changes in the base voltage, we now have gain of 8K/9K = -1dB gain, with another 3:1 attenuation in the 4 resistors going to GND. Gain of this part of the loop is still INVERTING, but -11dB gain.

Now place a Zener (or AP432 with 2 resistors to set the voltage) from base of transistor to the "regulated Vout. Also, so the "sense" zener/AP432 has current, place 1Kohm from base to GND.

Comment: The replacement NPN with its Re can't sink off the base current of T1002B => no regulation, allways maximum output voltage